# Icloud calendar retrieve event by uid via caldav

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, icloud, webdav, caldav

I'm trying to retrieve a specific ICloud event based on its UID via caldav protocol.

```
<C:calendar-query xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
<D:prop>
  <D:getetag/>
  <C:calendar-data>
    <C:comp name="VCALENDAR">
      <C:prop name="VERSION"/>
      <C:comp name="VEVENT">
        <C:prop name="SUMMARY"/>
        <C:prop name="UID"/>
        <C:prop name="DTSTART"/>
        <C:prop name="DTEND"/>
        <C:prop name="DURATION"/>
        <C:prop name="RRULE"/>
        <C:prop name="RDATE"/>
        <C:prop name="EXRULE"/>
        <C:prop name="EXDATE"/>
        <C:prop name="RECURRENCE-ID"/>
      </C:comp>
      <C:comp name="VTIMEZONE"/>
    </C:comp>
  </C:calendar-data>
</D:prop>
<C:filter>
  <C:comp-filter name="VCALENDAR">
    <C:comp-filter name="VEVENT">
      <C:prop-filter name="UID">
        <C:text-match>$$EVENT_UID$$</C:text-match>
      </C:prop-filter>
    </C:comp-filter>
  </C:comp-filter>
</C:filter>
```

When I replace the C:prop-filter name="UID" by C:prop-filter name="SUMMARY", the request works fine with a 204, but I try with the UID, I get a 403 Forbidden.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but just to make sure: Remember that text-match does a *substring* search. So if you ever do the above, make sure that you further filter the query results for an exact match. (e.g. one UID might be AA and another one AABB).

Comment: This is also not quite answering your question, but it might help you anyways: If you are trying to fetch events after listing them with PROPFIND or similar, I'd do that via the ``<href>``. Unlike fetching and querying by UID, it's mostly guaranteed to be supported by all servers that are not completely broken.

Answer (score 1):

iCloud doesn't support a pretty wide range of calendar-query requests. You may be stuck downloading the entire collection first.

Answer (score 0):

The url you are using to post request must contain ics file link along with the UID in request.